# Java function to find prime number not working

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, primes

The function takes in an integer N. The function must print all prime numbers from 2 to N (including N, if N is itself a prime number).

I have the function and it runs, but it is skipping some prime numbers and even including some even numbers like 8. I can't seem to find the bug that is causing this.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class PrimeNumbers {

    List <Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> findPrimes(int n){

        if(n == 2){
            primeList.add(n);
        }
        else{
            //should I have i=i+2 instead of i++ to move faster? 
           //If so, by doing this, it causes weird and different 
          //output when running
            for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
                if(n%i != 0){
                    primeList.add(i);
                }
            }

        }

        return (ArrayList<Integer>) primeList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeNumbers pn = new PrimeNumbers();

        System.out.println(pn.findPrimes(15));
    }

}
```

Comment: You have problem in your logic, you just iterate from 2 to n once, but you should have one function which checks whether number is prime or not, and call that function inside loop.

Comment: I want a function that takes in Number N, and returns an array of all prime numbers from 2 to N.

Comment: Make one function which checks whether number is prime or not and return boolean either true or false. Call that function inside your loop by passing loop counter as argument, if function returns true add that number in array list

Comment: Your algorithm is not correct. You have to check every 'i' if it is prime, but you check if 'n' is divisible by every 'i'. Ask google for 'prime sieve' and you ll get an efficient and working algorithm.

Comment: Just do 2 numbers on paper and you'll understand why what you've done has absolutely nothing to do with prime numbers. All you've done is find all the NOT factors of `n`.

Comment: @mikeyaworsk I understand the logic is wrong, and that I need to change it. But it wasn't even find the factors of N, because when I passed 15, I got number such as 4 and 8.

Comment: @EbadSaghar I changed my comment to be the *not* factors of `n`. It was a typo. Check my answer for more on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for finding prime numbers is incorrect.

Right now, what your code does is:
1. Iterate on all the integers up to N
2. Find any integer that N can't be divided by, and add them to the list.
This has nothing to do with prime numbers.

Instead, your code should do something like:
1. Iterate on all the integers up to N
2. For each of these integers (let's say M), run a sub-loop iterating on all integers below it, and checking if none of those integers can divide M.
If the sub-loop finishes without finding a divider of M, add M to the list - it's a prime number (can't be divided by any integer except 1 and itself).

Simple code for checking if a number (2 or above) is prime:

```
public boolean isPrime(int num)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

There are many optimisations for this and it's a world by itself.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code demonstrating this

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is entirely backwards. You can only say a number is prime if you've tested ALL possible divisors. You're currently adding ANY number which has a non-zero remainder, which is BACKWARDS. A non-zero remainder means it was NOT evenly divisible, meaning it's NOT a multiple of the factor you're testing, e.g.

```
8 % 3 -> 2
2 != 0 -> true
therefore 8 is prime
```

You can only do your `.add()` call AFTER you've finished the loop and no tests came back true:

```
is_prime = true; // assume prime
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
     if (n % 2 == 0) { // no remainder, even divisible, therefore NOT primt
         is_prime = false;
         break; // abort the loop, no point in testing more
     }
}
```

And yes, you can boost efficiency somewhat by starting your tests at 3 and jumping by 2. Since `2` is the only even prime, it is literally impossible for any OTHER even number to be prime, because 2 is a divisor of all even numbers. So test 3,5,7,9,etc...

e.g.

```
  test if `n` is even and `!= 2` - if so, then it's NOT prime
  run 3,5,7,... loop to test everything else
```

Answer (score 2):

All you've done is find the *not* factors of `n`. You test if each number leading up to it is a factor of `n` by adding it if `n % i != 0`.

What you need to do is iterate from 2 to n, and for *each* of those numbers, test if it's prime. You will need two loops. I suggest creating a method to determine prime numbers, and I guess your current method is find as it is. Just replace `if (n % i != 0)` with `if(isPrime(i))`

```
public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    // eliminate the simple cases
    if (n < 2) {
        return false;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    // only test up until the square root of that number
    for (int i = 2; i < Math.pow(n, 0.5) + 1; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false; // found a factor, it's not prime
        }
    }
    return true; // hasn't found a factor and returned false, so it's prime
}
```

And then in your current code:

```
for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
    if(n%i != 0){
        primeList.add(i);
    }
}
```

Just change `if(n%i != 0){` to `if(isPrime(i))`

So it would be this:

```
for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)) {
        primeList.add(i);
    }
}
```